# Show there exists an ordinal containing the natural numbers, with a special property

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to solve part (ii) of this question (attached), but have so far had little success. From seeing similar(ish) questions, I believe the approach they're looking for is constructing some set A using recursion, and showing the union of A has this property. For example A={w,w+1,w+2,...}, and A={w,w.2,w.4,w.8,...} are sets I have tried, but had no success with. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: $\epsilon_0 := \sup \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega},\cdots\}$ works.

Comment: Continous functions from the ordinals to the ordinals always have arbitrarily large fixed points. Here, $\mu \to 2^\mu$ is a continuous functions, therefore it has fixed points larger than, say $\omega_1$

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Max that's interesting to know, though I think at my level of studying the answer they were looking for is probably more along the line of Hanul's.

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa the proof of the general case really isn't more difficult than Hanul's answer. You take $f$ to be a continuous (increasing -I had forgotten to mention that) function, and $\alpha$ to be any ordinal. Then you consider the sequence $\alpha_0 = \alpha$, $\alpha_{n+1}=f(\alpha_n)$. Then you look at $\sup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n$

Comment: Thanks Max - that's easier than I thought :)